# Best approach to store time intervals

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE things
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 name TEXT,
 status INTEGER);
```

There are these "things" which have a status that can be 1 or 0, this status is changed automatically by another part of my program.
I would like to store information about the time intervals when these things status is 0 or 1, what can I do?
I thought to create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE status_from_0_to_1
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 datetime DATE,
 things_id INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES things (id));

CREATE TABLE status_from_1_to_0
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 datetime DATE,
 things_id INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES things (id));
```

But now I don't know how to write the query that check if the new status is different from the status in the table `things` and only in this case add a row in one of the two tables.
I don't know if this is the best approach, I also thought to create a single table (besides `things`) with two `DATE` fields but I think the query would be even more diffult.

Comment: Also, don't make the (extremely common) beginner mistake of thinking sqlite has an actual `DATE` type. Read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html for details.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the syntax, however this is an example I created ad hoc to expose my problem, it's not meant to be executed. I've already read something about the "fake" Date type, I'll take this opportunity to read your link and understand more.

Comment: Are you in charge of the part of program updating table? because if you are, you probably should create object at the same time so you don't have to do this. Also, one table is better -> you don't have to have from_0to1 and from1to0, just have a column saying that.

Comment: Yes I am, but I don't know how to write the query. I have to insert a row in this table only if the status field in the ’things’ table is set to a different value from the new. How can I achieve that?